# Maya 2015 Collada mesh transforms not applied

Tags: c++, directx, graphics, geometry, maya

I am trying to load a dae (Collada) model into my 3d engine. The problem is they export the vertices and transforms seperately. So in Maya 2015 it looks like this
[image]

In the game engine I have it simply read in vertices, normals, etc. It looks like this...

[image]

You can tell it loaded the model without any transformations. I would like it so it applies the transformations to the vertices before it exports them to the file. Does anyone know how to do this in Maya. It defaulted like that in maya on my old computer but not on my new one I just built. So now I can't make 3d geometry and load it in the engine.

NOTE: I am also using Assimp to load my models is there possibly a flag that would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when I switched computers I downloaded a more up to date version of Assimp that required me to use the "aiProcess_PreTransformVertices" flag whereas some older versions of Assimp do this already.